# multilevel exploratory factor analysis with repeated measurements

Tags: latent-variable

I need to perform an exploratory factor analysis on a group of subjects where each subject has a collection of repeated measurements: routinely self-reported data for some period of time.

**My question** is how to obtain the latent factors for the cohort and properly to take into account the differences between the subjects.

I can (theoretically) to obtain latent factor for each subject separately, but how then to make sense from the collection of individual latent factors?